# requirejs and angularjs 1.5 injection of ui.router failing for components

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, requirejs, components

I'm getting this error when using the recommended component loading method ([See step 3](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) )

```
  Error: Module name "angular-ui-router" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

app module definition:

```
<script>
  var adminApp = angular.module('adminClientApp', [require('angular-ui-router'), 'ngMaterial', 'ngResource', 'ngMessages', 'ngMdIcons']);
</script>
```

According to the doco, there isn't a need to include a script tag - it will be loaded via requirejs

Requirejs main.js definition:

```
  require.config({
    paths:{
        'angular-ui-router': 'vendor/angular-ui-router/release/'
    },
    shim:{
       'angular': {
          exports: 'angular'
     }
   }
  });
```

app layout:

```
  -- root
     index.html
     main.js
     -- js
         -- app (angular files here)
            app.js
     -- vendor (3rd party libs)
```

requirejs main.js setting in index.html

```
  <script data-main="main.js" src="vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide you are using is not made for RequireJS. After applying the instructions there, you are doing something like this:

```
<script>
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [require('angular-ui-router')]);
</script>
```

This will generally fail to work with RequireJS because calling `require` with a single string fails *unless the module is already loaded*. This call is guaranteed to work only if it is inside a `define`, like this:

```
define(function (require) {
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [require('angular-ui-router')]);
});
```

This code is a module which should be in a separate `.js` file and loaded with `require(['module name'])`. (Note that the parameter is an array of strings. This is a different form of `require` than the one that takes a single string parameter.)

You should use [Component](https://github.com/componentjs/component), which is what the author of the guide you are using was using when he/she wrote the guide, or a tool that is equivalent to it. Otherwise, you need to convert your code to work with RequireJS.

Comment: Oh wow, big detail I missed - thanks Louis. I'll load ui-router the normal way then. I thought component was referring to angularjs :-/